# Logging POST body size using morgan when request is received

Tags: node.js, api, express, post, morgan

I am using 'morgan' library to log my request, time it takes and the size of response.

But, for a POST request is there a way I can log the POST request and its body size when it is received?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After going through [morgan](https://vivia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/node_modules/morgan/README/) documentation for about an hour I found a good solution to the problem.

Instead of using [morgan-body](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan-body), logging can can be done using the [morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan) library itself at the time of request. Even the length of the POST body can be logged quite easily.

Here is how it can be done:

```
app.use(morgan({format: 'POST body length in bytes :req[Content-Length]', immediate: true}))
```

Here the 'format' option defines the format of log and the 'immediate' option writes the log at the time request is received

Answer (score 34):

1. Use custom token formats from Morgan module.
2. Create a token for body and then just add it to your format.

Here is the working sample code snippet you need to add to your `app.js`:

```js
morgan.token('body', (req, res) => JSON.stringify(req.body));
app.use(morgan(':method :url :status :response-time ms - :res[content-length] :body - :req[content-length]'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [morgan-body](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan-body) ,this captures all the request types whether be post or get

```
import morganBody from 'morgan-body';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();

// must parse body before morganBody as body will be logged
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// hook morganBody to express app
morganBody(app);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own middleware

```
 app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    next();
  });
```

You can also check if the request is either POST or PUT etc..

```
if (req.method === "POST") {
       // log the budy
    }
```